# Chrome extension: content script to popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This extension scans DOM for text with V + digits `e.g. V123, V333, V1, V21321321`, and if the text is hovered it will send an API request from `content.js` and returns data. But the data should be displayed in popup and I can't seem to set it using `document.getElementById('headline').innerHTML = data` because it is null. Is there a way around it?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AAAAA",
  "description": "AAAAA Descriptionnnnnn",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="headline" class="headline" style="background-color: #ccc; width: 300px;">
    This is a headline
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

content.js

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*')

// loop through all element
for (let x = 0; x < elements.length; x++) {
  let element = elements[x]

  // loop through all nodes in an element
  for (let y = 0; y < element.childNodes.length; y++) {
    let node = element.childNodes[y]

    // if node is a text node
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      const searchText = new RegExp(/V\d+/gi)
      const text = node.nodeValue
      const matchFound = text.match(searchText)

      if (matchFound) {
        element.classList.add('serialcode')
      }
    }
  }
}

const serials = document.getElementsByClassName('serialcode')
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'

Array.from(serials).forEach((serial) => {
  serial.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    let getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'get'
      })
      return response.json()
    }
    getData().then(data => {
      document.getElementById('headline').innerHTML = data
      console.log(data)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: You need to load a separate script popup.js in your popup.html. It will communicate with content script via [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: There's an error when I tried it 
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`
Why is it?

Comment: The popup runs only when shown. It means the popup should send a message to the content script first.